# How to get values of other fields if a row is having duplicate entries in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have a table like this:

```
ID   build1   build2  test    status
1    John     ram     test1   pass
2    john     shyam   test2   fail
3    tom      ram     test1   fail
```

The problem that I am facing is - on one of my webpage, only the values from the column "uild1" are available to me. Now in table there are 2 entries corresponding to "John". so, even if the user selects different "John", its showing the values for other values from the row only. On my webpage, in the drop down list, user can see 2 "John" but since query has been made using "John" condition, on both occasions, its showing the results from the first row only.

Comment: Have you used an upper or a lower for the column `build1` while framing the query??

Comment: can you post your sql query and drop-down code???

Comment: what will be your desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.build1 NOT IN(SELECT t2.build1
                   FROM table1 t2
                   GROUP BY t2.build1
                   HAVING COUNT(t2.build1) > 1);
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df965/2)

This will give you only:

```
| ID | BUILD1 | BUILD2 |  TEST | STATUS |
-----------------------------------------
|  3 |    tom |    ram | test1 |   fail |
```

Since, it is the only row that has no duplicate `build1`.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, given a web page with 2 johns available to click on, how can you get each result accordingly?  Unfortunately, there is no way of doing this with just SQL.

In your PHP code, if you can pass a parameter to your SQL code with either the ID or a counter/row number, then you could query the database to return a corresponding unique record.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from yourtable where build1 == 'john' limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You build1 is not unique or primary key so it is picking all the row matching your condition. You should use primary key or unique key to find the result. In your select drop-down your option value should be uniq/primary key so when you select particular "John" it will get result of that john.

```
   select * from table_name where id=params[:id] ;
```

If you post some more information. It will be helpful to write better code for you.